# Как передать в .netrc параметры авторизации для Amazon S3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon

Как передать в .netrc параметры авторизации для Amazon S3
Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: а программа, которой вы пользуетесь, умеет это делать?

Comment: Разве curl не умеет это делать?

Comment: В принципи проблему решил другим способом, но если кто знает, делитесь